# Width="*" in longlistselector giving error "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I used DataTemplateSelector example as shown in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821165/longlistselector-different-item-template-for-first-and-last-item) and modified it a little to suit my requirements as shown below.

```
public abstract class TemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    public abstract DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container);

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        var parent = GetParentByType<LongListSelector>(this);

        ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, this);
    }

    private static T GetParentByType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        T result = null;
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

        while (parent != null)
        {
            result = parent as T;

            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        return null;
    }
}


public class MyTemplateSelector : TemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate one { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate two { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate three { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate four { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate five { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate six { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate seven { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate eight { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate nine { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        PoiData poiItem = item as PoiData;

        if (poiItem != null)
        {
            switch (poiItem.Type)
            {
                case "atm":
                    return one;

                case "food":
                    return two;

                case "hospital":
                    return three;

                case "police":
                    return four;

                case "pharmacy":
                    return five;

                case "gas_station":
                    return six;

                case "hindu_temple":
                    return seven;

                case "train_station":
                    return eight;

                case "movie_theater":
                    return nine;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my xaml looks like this.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="one">
        <StackPanel Height="75">
            <Grid Height="65"
                  Background="Red"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"          
                  Margin="0, 0, 0, 12">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="65"
                                  Height="65"
                                  Background="White"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Width="auto">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
.
.
.
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectingTemplate">
            <local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}"
                                      one="{StaticResource one}"
                                      two="{StaticResource two}"
                                      three="{StaticResource three}"
                                      four="{StaticResource four}"
                                      five="{StaticResource five}"
                                      six="{StaticResource six}"
                                      seven="{StaticResource seven}"
                                      eight="{StaticResource eight}"
                                      nine="{StaticResource nine}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is the panorama item xaml

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AroundMe, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="12,-20,0,75"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Poi.Items}"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectingTemplate}"
                                        SelectionChanged="PoiSelectionChanged" >
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

My problem is, if I use this code, the `stackpanel` always aligns itself to the center of the `panorama` item no matter if I set `HorizontalAlignment` to `left` or `right` or `stretch`.

And if I set the `width` property of either the `stackpanel` or the child `grid` to `*` to take up the entire screen space, I get an error which I think is completely irrelevant.

```
{MS.Internal.WrappedException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. ---> System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth,     Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---}
```

What exactly am I supposed to do to set the `stackpanel`'s width to take up the entire screen width ? Is there any workaround ?

And why is this exception throwing when I set the `width` to `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thing to solve your problem

1. Remove the parent stackpanel and only have the Grid as the content of the DataTemplate
2. Set the Width of the second ColumnDefinition to '*'

Why does this work?

1. StackPanels are built to consume as little space as possible. So having a StackPanel as the "parent element" or the content of the DataTemplate makes your content "shrink" to only as much space as it is **told** (by setting *explicit* widths).
2. The second column of the grid was told to "auto" size. That means take up only as much space as *needed* to render (just like the StackPanel was doing!). Setting the size to "*" tells the columns to take as much space as *available*.

Comment: That was informative. But removing the `stackpanel` as the parent element and setting the width of second ColumnDefinition to `*` still doesn't solve it. 

The `grid` element still takes space only till the length of the textblock element. It throws the same exception if I explicitly set the `width` of second `grid` or the `textblock` inside the second `grid` to `*`.

What do you think might be wrong ?

Comment: Venkatapathi, did you ever fix your problem? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: is your Panorama contained within an element that would restrict the width? another stackpanel? something with the width set?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! I found it Googling here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KDZZtrw9eG0J:y2bd.me/blog/2013/08/16/fixing-alignment-issues-with-datatemplateselector/+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Basically, the XAML tag that references your TemplateSelector needs to have HorizontalContentAlignment set to stretch.  Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YourTemplateSelectorKey">
    <namespace:YourTemplateSelectorClass HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ... />
</DataTemplate>
```

Tada!